# My JSON.parse in app.js doesnt function properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, express, google-api

**app.js**:

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.get("/",function(req,res){
  const url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/jsonaddress=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY;
      console.log(response.statusCode);
    response.on("data",function(data){
      var jatin=JSON.parse(data);
      console.log(jatin);
  })
})

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

Error on Console

> app.listen(3000,function(){   console.log("server started on port
>   3000"); })
>
> server started on port 3000 200 undefined:26
>                   "long_name"
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/jatin/Downloads/full_stack/Web-Development/maps/app.js:11:21)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:189:13)
>       at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:487:10)
>       at flow (_stream_readable.js:931:34)
>       at resume_ (_stream_readable.js:912:3)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting

**The output is visible when I run it on browser but on the console it throws an error.**
 For some reason JSON.parse() isn't working as expected.

I am trying to make a geocoding API call and in response, it gives me a JSON output...
which when I enter it as a URL on the browser the expected output is received
But when app.js is run on a node express server and when I hit my localhost:3000 I am getting the console error

Apparently the JSON.parse("data") is working but stops unexpectedly. Which leads to error.

Comment: Can you please add you response data structure ?

Comment: "data" gets triggered for each *chunk* in the stream. You have to collect all *chunks*, then combine them into the whole response, then call `JSON.parse` on it. Or use a library that supports parsing streams (e.g. `fetch`)

Comment: response.on("data",function(data){
          var jatin=JSON.parse(data);
          console.log(jatin);                                                                                                        --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------that is what I am doing... collecting an entire stream of response in var Jatin

Comment: try logging data without JSON.parse share the log, response may be not a valid parse-able JSON.f

Comment: Kindly add logged data in your question itself. It will be helpful to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your code to perform JSON.parse on `end` event instead, like this example form the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback):

```
http.get('http://nodejs.org/dist/index.json', (res) => {
  const { statusCode } = res;
  const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

  let error;
  if (statusCode !== 200) {
    error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                      `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
  } else if (!/^application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    error = new Error('Invalid content-type.\n' +
                      `Expected application/json but received ${contentType}`);
  }
  if (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    // Consume response data to free up memory
    res.resume();
    return;
  }

  res.setEncoding('utf8');
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
  res.on('end', () => {
    try {
      const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
      console.log(parsedData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
  });
}).on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
});
```

Notice that this is [http.get](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_url_options_callback), but it should be the same for [https.get](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_get_options_callback), so in your code the `on('data')` should be used to assemble the chunks before your perform `JSON.parse()` on it.

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const app = express();

const port = 3000;

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  const url = "API_URL";
  https.get(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response.statusCode);
    let body = "";
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      body += data;
    });

    response.on("end", function() {
      console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    });
  });
  res.end("End data response");
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

basically `.on('end', callback')` and `.on('data', callback')` are event listener to `data` receive and request `end` **events**, and to be able to handle your requests response in node when using `http(s).get` you have to attache an event listener on `data` event which is invoked every time your request receives a chunk of the request response, and once the request ended by the service the event `end` will be invoked stating that there is no more data from the server requested hence the request ended.

as stated in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest):

> The callback must take care to consume the response data for reasons
>   stated in http.ClientRequest section.

Comment: Yess The Code worked ^^ understood the concept. Thanks for the effort mate. Appreciated.   `response.on("data",function(data){
      body+ = data; ` does the job.

Comment: glad to help :)

Comment: `response.on("end",function(){

      console.log(JSON.parse(body));
    });      
  })`   Can you explain this code for more clarity and mentioning what is `end` in `response.on("end",function()`

Comment: Brother, I want to pick content from the middle and not the end of response data. So can you update the answer accordingly?  Thanks for the constant help.

Comment: I updated my answer, to explain the `.on('end')`, "I want to pick content from the middle and not the end of response data" I don't understand what you want here, you can't do that, since the request should end before you can do a JSON.parse on it, maybe I'm missing what you want here

Comment: Let me clarify again. I want the content of the full response and not chunks of it.
According to your solution, we are only getting the end of the response. But we require contents from above the end portion.

Comment: @MahirGada, when we use `.on('end')` you get the full content response that we built inside `.on('data')` event handler. so you are good to use this code as per the documentation of the `https.get`